# jQuery deleting cookie on tab close

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I want show ad only if user open site first time in this tab, it mean that if use open site ad must b shown, but if not close this tab and open for example some link, when ad will be not show ?

My question is how to remove cookies on tab close or also can be solution remove old cookies on tab open, add setting new, but then will be a problem to solve what cookie is new/old.

I'm using this cookies library: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: why don't you use session storage?

Comment: or reverse your thinking - set a cookie after they visit the first time.

Comment: @DanielA.White ok for example I'm will store cookie after user visit site first time, but how to solve this situation: user open second tab and I want show ad in this tab becaus user visit ffirstly, but I check cookies and it's already set ?